# Converting Python functions to classes for reusability

Tags: python, class, code-reuse, reusability

I have a piece of written code,

```
class Corpus:
    def __init__(self):
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self

    def getwords():
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__":

    texts = []
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
            texts.append(str(filename))
    else:
        print("Error!", sys.stderr())

    removables = [".", ",", "!", "?", "(", ")"]

    text = ""
    for filename in texts:
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                text += line
    words = text.lower().split()

    allwords = {}
    for word in words:
        for removable in removables:
            if removable in word:
                word = word.replace(removable, "")
        if word in allwords:
            allwords[word] += 1
        else:
            allwords[word] = 1
    print(allwords)

    wordsearch = input("Enter word to search : ")
    filesearch = input("Enter file to search in: ")
    with open(filesearch) as f2:
        for line in f2:
            if wordsearch in line:
                print(line)

    wordsunique = len(allwords)
    wordtotal = len(words)
    filetotal = len(texts)


    print("Total number of words: ", wordtotal)
    print("Total number of unique words: ", wordsunique)
    print("Total number of files: ", filetotal)
```

It's a simple wordcounter. I would like to, however, rather put the sections that determine the filename and word to search for into a class so that the code os reusable for a bigger project I'm working on. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is one method per task e.g.

```
class WordCounter(object):

    def __call__(*filenames):

        self.validate_arguments(filenames)

        all_words = self.get_words_from_files(filenames)

        counted_words = self.count_all_words()

        word_to_search_for = self.get_word_from_user()
```

That along with giving everything sensible names tends to make life easier for reuse. Sensible names makes it easy to know what the method does, one method per task makes it easy to reuse. If a method does a lot of work then it becomes very specialized and is unlikely to be able to be reused a lot.

I recommend checking out a book like [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/Default.aspx) if you want to read more on the subject or check out some [google answers](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=how%20to%20design%20reusable%20classes).

Comment: I would not mix input-handling (self.get_word_from_user()) with processing logic in one single class. That reduces reusability. See the MVC design pattern. I am also not sure, if starting with a (rather complex) class will help MAK to understand what the basic principles of reuse are.

Comment: Of course FearofPython was the questioner, not MAK -- can not correct it any more in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

When you just want to have a reusable word-counter, you don't need necessarily a class.

Maybe you are fine with a simple function:

```
def wordCounter(fileName, word):
   ...
```

Of course it depends on how you want to use the functionality. Do you need to divide the functionality in parts, as it is demonstrated in the parallel post, than go with his solution. But when you just want to reuse the word counter as a whole thing, one single function could suffice. You also can split the functionality, when you use pure functions without classes. To split the functionality in different functions makes sense to have it better structured and better understandable code.

But a simple word-counter does not necessarily need to be a class. When it has more functionality, like filters or lists of stop-words, than I would also tend to use a class.

Classes are not needed for reuse -- reuse was done long before classes existed. Your problem is that you have done all your coding at the module level, which prevents reuse. Functions were invented to foster reuse. Classes are also used for reuse, but at a higher level. When you have mastered functions and maybe learned some theory on classes, I would suggest that you read something like this book: [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), or other books about the topic.